# Symfony tips & advices

Tags: php, model-view-controller, frameworks, symfony1

I'm developing Code Igniter as framwork and i want to switch to Symfony but the problem is that I don't even know if I have bad habits with MVC or Framwork in general.

I know it's a quite subjective question, but I thought it could be a good idea to ask people who has already practice with this framework.

So if you have some Do's and Dont's about framworks in general or more accurately about Symfony I would be grateful !

Timon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Documentation on the Symfony website is all you need - its very extensive and will help you learn the framework quickly and in depth

Answer (score 2):

Check your applications before deployment with list on http://symfony-check.org/

Answer (score 1):

These are some tips:

1. Don't modify css/javascript codes from the web directory, you
   must edit them in your src bundles, then assets:install, and
   assetic:dump.
2. Never try to mix PHP and twig codes
3. Never edit the framework bundles (the vendors folder)
4. Use fixtures for your tests.
5. Try to avoid dependencies between bundles. Every bundle should be
   independent of the others.